# PiHole in docker no webserver

Tags: raspbian-buster, docker, lighttpd, pi-hole

I'm trying to get PiHole to run in a docker on my raspberry pi 4. For some reason I'm unable to solve an issue with lighttpd.

docker-compose.yaml:

```
  pihole:
    container_name: pihole
    image: pihole/pihole:latest
    network_mode: host
    environment:
      TZ: 'Europe/Amsterdam'
      WEBPASSWORD: 'helloW0rld' # temporary
      SERVERIP: 192.168.178.5
    volumes:
       - './etc-pihole/:/etc/pihole/'
       - './etc-dnsmasq.d/:/etc/dnsmasq.d/'
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1
      - 1.1.1.1
    # Recommended but not required (DHCP needs NET_ADMIN)
    #   https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole#note-on-capabilities
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    restart: unless-stopped
```

command:

```
docker-compose up -d pihole; docker-compose logs -tf --tail="50" pihole
```

Provides a returning error such as below:

```
pihole           | 2020-02-17T18:43:24.256524171Z Starting lighttpd
pihole           | 2020-02-17T18:43:24.364843550Z 2020-02-17 19:43:24: (network.c.464) can't bind to port: 127.0.0.1 80 Address already in use 
pihole           | 2020-02-17T18:43:24.382772710Z Stopping lighttpd
pihole           | 2020-02-17T18:43:24.389610163Z lighttpd: no process found
```

I've added `SERVERIP` already as environment variable as suggested in this [issue tracker](https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/issues/432) but it doesn't make any difference as without adding this variable.

Comment: "Can't bind to port, address already in use" means something is listening on the HTTP port already, which is a bit odd if that's a single purpose container.

Comment: My thoughts exactly

Comment: You need to be root (or have CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE) to listen on ports <1024. Could it be related to that?

Comment: I'm not a docker expert but I would expect the setup of the container to be executed as root.

Comment: Not necessarily, as that is not automatically desirable.  You should try starting it `docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN`.  But I don't think this will throw "address in use", it will throw "permission denied".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the issue was caused by capitalizing `SERVERIP` while I should've been using `ServerIP`. Changing the capitalization allowed me to access the web interface again.